# Make --output-sync can't redirect output to /dev/null

Tags: linux, makefile, dev-null

I build a binary file using command

```
make -j8 --output-sync
```

And it works fine, but when I try to redirect output to /dev/null it hangs forever.
The command is:

```
make -j8 --output-sync > /dev/null
```

In case I set the option --output-sync=recurse not even Ctrl+C terminate make.
Any suggestion?

Comment: This must mean that some other process on your system has `/dev/null` locked.  Maybe some other make process, or something else.  The next version of GNU make will use a separate temporary file for locking instead of `stdout` (it's a little unfortunate because there are some very useful capabilities enabled by locking stdout, such as avoiding sync locking for sub processes that redirect output, but it ends up being too problematic).

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I don't think that this is the case because "make -j8 > /dev/null" works fine, the issue is with the option --output-sync. In addition, if a just redirect the output to a file like "make -j8 --output-sync > /tmp/dummy.txt" it works just fine.

Comment: Everything you wrote _confirms_ my analysis, rather than denying it.  The way output sync works (in current versions of GNU make) is that it takes a lock on the stdout file descriptor so only one make writes to stdout at a time.  If you redirect stdout to a file that is already locked by something else, then output will hang until you unlock that thing.  Obviously this has no impact if you don't use output sync since in that case nothing is locked.  And if you redirect output to another file like `/tmp/dummy.txt` which is **not** locked already, then everything works fine.